# Scala: how do I understand the curry mechanism

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I understand how does a curried function work in practice.

```
def plainSum(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
val plusOne = plainSum(1) _
```

where `plusOne` is a curried function of type `(Int) => Int`, which can be applied to an `Int`:

```
plusOne(10)
res0: Int = 11
```

Independently, when reading the book (Chapter 2) *Functional Programming in Scala*, by Chiusano and Bjarnason, it demonstrated that the implementation of currying a function `f` of two arguments into a function of one argument can be written in the following way:

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) = 
  a: A => b: B => f(a, b)
```

Reference: https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/gettingstarted/GettingStarted.scala#L157-L158

I can understand the above implementation, but have a hard time associating the signature with the `plainSum` and `plusOne` example.

The `1` in the `plainSum(1) _`  seems to correspond to the type parameter `A`, and the function value `plusOne` seems to correspond to the function signature `B => C`.

How does the Scala compiler apply the above `curry` signature when seeing the statement `plainSum(1) _`?

Comment: The premise of your question is flawed. *"How does the Scala compiler apply the above curry signature when seeing the statement plainSum(1) _?"* - It doesn't. `plainSum` is a method. `f: (A, B) => C` is an object of type `Function2[A, B, C]`. The currying of the former does not have much to do with the currying of the latter, except for the somewhat vague formal similarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating partially applying a function with currying. In Scala, they some differences:

- A partially applied function passes less arguments than provided in the application with the rest of the arguments, represented by the placeholder(_), is partially applied on the next call.
- Currying is when a higher order function takes a function of N arguments and transforms it into a one-arg chains of functions.

The `plusOne` example is naturally curried out of the box by virtue of the multi-parameter list which takes a function of one argument successively and return the last argument.

`Your mistake is that you are trying to use currying twice when this notation()() already gives you currying.`
 Meanwhile you can achieve same effect by currying the `plainSum` signature to the `curry` function like so:

```
def curry[A, B, C](f: (A, B) => C): A => (B => C) =
  (a: A) => (b: B) => f(a, b)

def plainSum(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b

val curriedSum = curry(plainSum)
val add2 = curriedSum(2)
add2(3)
```

Both(partial application and currying) shouldn't be confused with another concept called partial functions.

Note: The red book, fpinscala, tried creating those abstraction as done in the Scala library without the syntactic sugar.